# Android: Application crashes because of presenter error?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp, presenter

I'm try to develop an android app in Kotlin. I'm using an **MVP design pattern**. Unfortunately, the application crashes due to an error in the presenter. Below the screenshot of the logcat and you can check my code at [Github](http://github.com/ariefpurnamamuharram/MyFootballApplication).

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you.

[image: LogCat]

Comment: Have you check out my GitHub? I've already updated it but it'still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring:

```
private lateinit var swipeRefresh: SwipeRefreshLayout
```

then re-declare the same variable in `onActivtyCreated`:

```
val swipeRefresh = rootView.findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipe_refresh)
```

try to delete `val` to use the class variable `swipeRefresh`.

Comment: I've already update my GitHub. Please check it. It's still doesn't work

Comment: i will try it, hope can found something.

Comment: I found the problem.
the problem is your `data.lastMatch` is null, but your not make that variable to get `null`. so that's error will say not-null is null.

so I change some your list become:

`var lastMatch: List<LastMatch> = ArrayList()`

I look you create `gson` and `apiRequest` in fragment, I am recommended to move all that to presenter because your use MVP.